# Have to CTRL+ALT+DEL to get GRUB menu HP Pavilion ze2000 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: boot, grub2, restart

I've got a HP Pavilion ze2000 with a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and after I got my wireless working, (https://askubuntu.com/questions/266408/12-10-hp-pavilion-ze2000-wireless-doesnt-work) I'm ready to tackle this GRUB menu issue.  From a cold start or on reboot, I have to CTRL+ALT+DEL to get the GRUB menu to come up so I can boot.  At first I would power off then back on to get it, but after a while I figured out that CAD works as well.

I've done `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` so everything should be up to date (I think).  This is my first Ubuntu install but I have played with a couple other linux flavors.

After the GRUB menu comes up, the machine will boot no problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with CAD. This happen **only** after a restart, right?

Comment: CAD = CTRL+ALT+DEL.  It happens when I restart and when I power on after having had the machine off for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but since my machine is different and I am using Lubuntu 14.04, I didn't post here. For documentation purposes, the solution I found is this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/612714/121101.

**Summarizing:**

Comment out these options:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Change this line to look like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Comment: Updated the answer to contain the main points of the other answer :)