# Lubuntu 14.04 - No grub screen. Need to Ctrl Alt Del to reach grub

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

Turning the machine on or rebooting leads to a black screen right after the brand logo (Acer) splash screen. Nothing happens until I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del, which kind of reboots but shows the grub menu. At this point I can choose the system and boot normally. The system works fine, but having to do this each time I turn the computer on is not nice. [Related question without answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/266416/121101).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your `/etc/default/grub` file contains these two lines:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Can't understand why they leave these options there, since they are deprecated in favor of `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` according to `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`.

Commenting out these two options make the grub menu appears right away when booting (idea taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/281879/121101)). This leads to another problem that initially I didn't have: after choosing the option from grub, the system hangs in a black screen. To solve this one, go back to `/etc/default/grub` and change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Besides commenting out the two hidden timeout options mentioned, I also added `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=2`. This way the grub menu is hidden but if during the 2 seconds interval you press ESC you get the menu back. Otherwise you boot to your default option.

**UPDATE:**
You might leave `quiet splash` before `nomodeset` to keep the good looking boot process:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

The `nomodeset` introduced a new problem for me: can't control brightness anymore with fn keys. Once I figure a solution I'll update this.